EBS volume new adding forces ami changes via terraform
I am trying to add 3 additional ebs volumes to an existing running EC2 windows instance via terraform. The instance already has 3 volumes attached.
Adding these new volumes is forcing an ami change because of which it shows destroy and recreate of the ec2 instance in the plan. The terraform code already has ami attribute included in ignore lifecycle change.its strange considering a similar code is working in another application infra but with upgraded TF version.
Below are the code snippets of different sections in terraform. Attached screenshot of one block of terraform plan from ebs volume change.
Appreciated any inputs/workaround this problem if anyone faced similar issues adding new ebs volumes
TF version
required_version = ">= 0.13"

TF ignore lifecycle
lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [ami, private_ip, root_block_device]
  }

ebs block device property attribute
db_instance_ebs_block_device = [
  {
    device_name           = "xvdb"
    snapshot_id           = null
    volume_type           = "gp2"
    volume_size           = 150
    delete_on_termination = "true"
    encrypted             = "true"
  }]

ebs block device addition dynamic code
for_each = var.root_block_device == null ? [] : tolist([var.root_block_device])
    content {
      volume_type           = lookup(root_block_device.value, "volume_type", null)
      volume_size           = lookup(root_block_device.value, "volume_size", null)
      iops                  = lookup(root_block_device.value, "iops", null)
      delete_on_termination = lookup(root_block_device.value, "delete_on_termination", null)
      encrypted             = lookup(root_block_device.value, "encrypted", null)
      kms_key_id            = lookup(root_block_device.value, "kms_key_id", null)
    }
  }


Plan block screen shot

Not sure I understand how adding the volumes changes the AMI? Can you share that part of the plan output as well?

@MarkoE added just plan of ami change block screen shot. its a lenghty plan.

Where does the AMI ID come from? How did it change? Btw, unless you are using a custom AMI, there is no need to hide the AMI ID. :)

the new ami comes from our internal standard ami bakery which is custom. But tht gets polled only when ami change is excluded from ignore lifecycle. So it shouldn't  consider ami change in plan. Also, we dont have any drift from state file ami value and actual ami in aws console

Consider using a Terraform module specifically designed for attaching EBS volumes to existing instances. These modules often handle managing attachments through aws_ebs_volume and aws_volume_attachment resources while keeping the aws_instance configuration untouched. This approach provides more flexibility for adding/removing volumes without triggering AMI changes.
Here are some resources to get you started:
Terraform Registry - EC2 instance with EBS volume attachment: https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/ec2-instance/aws/latest/examples/volume-attachment
Stack Overflow discussion on attaching multiple EBS volumes with Terraform: Creating Multiple AWS EBS volumes and attach it to an instance using Terraform

thats the next goal to try with new volumes. wonder how that will impact exisitng volumes inside root block. the goal is to delete them once the new volume are attached and move data from old.
